# Contingency table based on third variable (numeric)

Tags: r

Some time ago I asked a question about creating market basket data. Now I would like to create a similar data.frame, but based on a third variable. Unfortunately I run into problems trying. Previous question: [Effecient way to create market basket matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723188/effecient-way-to-create-market-basket-matrix-in-r)
@shadow and @SimonO101 gave me good answers, but I was not able to alter their anwser correctly. I have the following data:

```
Customer <- as.factor(c(1000001,1000001,1000001,1000001,1000001,1000001,1000002,1000002,1000002,1000003,1000003,1000003))
Product <- as.factor(c(100001,100001,100001,100004,100004,100002,100003,100003,100003,100002,100003,100008))
input <- data.frame(Customer,Product)
```

I can create a contingency table now the following way:

```
input_df <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(input))
```

However I have a third (numeric) variable which I want as output in the table.

```
Number <- c(3,1,-4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 
input <- data.frame(Customer,Product,Number)
```

Now the code (of course, now there are 3 variables) does not work anymore. The result I am looking for has unique Customer as row names and unique Product as column names. And has Number as value (or 0 if not present), this number could be calculated by:

```
input_agg <- aggregate( Number ~ Customer + Product, data = input, sum)
```

Hope my question is clear, please comment if something is not clear.

Comment: +1 for another reproducible example.

Comment: Are you able to complete the `aggregate` step successfully?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `xtabs` for that :

```
R> xtabs(Number~Customer+Product, data=input)

         Product
Customer  100001 100002 100003 100004 100008
  1000001      0      1      0      2      0
  1000002      0      0      3      0      0
  1000003      0      1      1      0      1
```

Comment: @SimonO101 In fact, I just discovered it :-)

Comment: I think it's not a question of efficiency but of how much RAM you have on your system. Whatever method you use to compute it, you will always end up with a 90000x2000 table to store in memory...

Comment: @juba, That is correct indeed, should had known that it wouldn't fit.

Answer (score 4):

This class of problem is designed for `reshape2::dcast`...

```
require( reshape2 )
#  Too many rows so change to a data.table.
dcast( input , Customer ~ Product , fun = sum , value.var = "Number" )
#  Customer 100001 100002 100003 100004 100008
#1  1000001      0      1      0      2      0
#2  1000002      0      0      3      0      0
#3  1000003      0      1      1      0      1
```

---

Recently, the method for using `dcast` with `data.table` object was implemented by @Arun responding to [**FR #2627**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2627&group_id=240&atid=978). Great stuff. You will have to use the development version [**1.8.11**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240). Also at the moment, it should be used as `dcast.data.table`. This is because `dcast` is not a S3 generic yet in `reshape2` package. That is, you can do:

```
require(reshape2)
require(data.table)
input <- data.table(input)   
dcast.data.table(input , Customer ~ Product , fun = sum , value.var = "Number")
#    Customer 100001 100002 100003 100004 100008
# 1:  1000001      0      1      0      2      0
# 2:  1000002      0      0      3      0      0
# 3:  1000003      0      1      1      0      1
```

This should work quite well on bigger data and should be much faster than `reshape2:::dcast` as well.

---

Alternatively, you can try the `reshape:::cast` version which may or may not crash... Try it!!

```
require(reshape)
input <- data.table( input )
cast( input , Customer ~ Product , fun = sum , value = .(Number) )
```

Comment: Fast respons, this works indeed. However it makes my R session crash instandly. I updated my question.

Comment: @Freddy see update. Use a `data.table`. dcast methods have been written for these. Should be fast and avoid crashing your computer!

Comment: @Freddy but with a `data.table` rather than a `data.frame`? That is an important difference! Also, if you don't assign the output to a variable it will try to print to console and it will probably crash, so try and copy/paste this... `input <- data.table( input ); output <- dcast( input , Customer ~ Product , fun = sum , value.var = "Number" )`

Comment: Hmmmm, why don't you try with a subset of the data, e.g. the first `100k` rows? e.g. `dcast( input[ 1:1e5 , ] ... )` see if that works and build up from there?

Comment: @Freddy perhaps you are seeing [**this problem**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16136390/1478381)... too many groups.

Comment: yes that looks like the same problem. A problem i should had seen coming, as juba mentioned. Thanks for you effort, I accepted juba's answer for now as it only uses base R. I will check the performance of both methods and accept the fastest :)

Comment: yes that works! It gives a "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 630.8 Mb" which was expected now. But it does not crash my R anymore.

Comment: Alternatively, if they can get to the `input_agg` step from their question, why not just use `dcast` on that? `dcast(input_agg, Customer ~ Product, value.var="Number", fill = 0)`

Comment: @AnandaMahto they can't. Check the edits. I believe that crashes.

Comment: @SimonO101, made some edits, cleared up some things better. Hope it's alright.

Comment: @Arun thanks very much for clearing that up. Hopefully this solution will work now...

Comment: @Freddy see Arun's edit... use `dcast.data.table` not `dcast`. This will hopefully work now.