# R caret random forest script failing to load

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation, r-caret

I'm trying to build a machine learning model using caret's build in rf method.

when i do my cross-validation it uses about 6 GB of Ram but nothing happens?

My data set is 11.000 obs. with 16 variables. all of them are either intergers, numeric, factor.  My code is:

```
trainControl <- trainControl(method ="cv", number = 10)
metricType <- "Accuracy"

## Random Forest ##

set.seed(10)
model.rf <- train(Udmeldt~., data = TrainData, method="rf", metric = metricType, trControl = trainControl)
```

i'm running it on a win 10, with 8 GB ram.

Comment: Our dataset has a column with names for the 11.000 obs. these are all factor variables does that play a role?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"?

Comment: it just keeps loading without returning a output or error message

Comment: You're probably running out of memory and thrashing the hard disk. Try tweaking the RF parameters to reduce the model size, eg limit the no. of trees to 20 or 50.

Comment: How many variables are factors and what is the total amount of levels in those factors? Try using `method = "ranger"`

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449588/r-memory-management-advice-caret-model-matrices-data-frames) is relevant. Be sure to check out the comments too.

Comment: Thanks Hong Ooi for the help. i limmited the amount of trees and it helped!